# Rails 2.3.8 attributes read error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server-2005

- Rails 2.3.8
- Windows Server 2003
- Server SQL Server 2005

Uhm, this error makes absolutely no sense at all. I've checked it several times. Here is an example of the console.

```
>> s = SaleItemArchive.find(118296)
=> #<SaleItemArchive id: 118296, sale_id: 60308, item_id: 19825, quantity: 40, p    rice: 0.75, created_at: "1998-08-10 00:00:00", quantity_shipped: 0>
>> s.created_at
=> nil
>> s.attributes["created_at"]
=> Mon Aug 10 00:00:00 UTC 1998
>>
>> s.class.match_attribute_method?("created_at")
=> nil
>> s.class.generated_methods.include?("created_at")
=> false
>>
```

Here's an example of a normal one.

```
>> s = SaleItemArchive.find(118297)
=> #<SaleItemArchive id: 118297, sale_id: 60309, item_id: 2931, quantity: 100, price: 0.07, created_at: "1998-08-10 00:00:00", quantity_shipped: 0>
>> s.created_at
=> Mon, 10 Aug 1998 00:00:00 PDT -07:00
>> s.attributes["created_at"]
=> Mon Aug 10 00:00:00 UTC 1998
```

I've tested it on dozens of other rows in the database and this is the only row in the entire database that gives me a problem. It makes absolutely no sense. Since there are no errors given, it took me a while to figure out what was going wrong. Any ideas?

I tried checking and for some reason the attribute method is not created. I've tried duplicating this problem with new rows, editing other rows etc. Nothing. Please help.

Comment: Updated it. Please check it out.

Comment: very strange ... show your model code?

Comment: Have you looked at the 118296 row directly in MSSQL Management Studio and compared it to other rows? Just to make sure there isn't any weird data in that row..

Answer (score 0):

Most probably case is the row in the database is just missing the row. The object still responds to the `created_at` method (since it doesn't throw an error), so the only explanation is that the column is null for that row.

Comment: Read the included console output more carefully: `=> #<SaleItemArchive id: 118296, sale_id: 60308, item_id: 19825, quantity: 40, price: 0.75, created_at: "1998-08-10 00:00:00", quantity_shipped: 0>`, there is a `created_at` in there. Also note the `s.attributes["created_at"]` result.
`

Comment: How are you generating the `created_at` dates? The `attributes['created_at']` for your normal and your bad record are the same, in addition `s.created_at` for your normal record is returning id PDT instead of UTC (so they appear to be not the same time?).

Comment: The generated Rails accessor method applies a timezone adjustment, hence the difference between `s.created_at` and `s.attributes["created_at"]`. I don't know where Mike's `created_at` values are coming from.

Comment: It's not the timezone difference that strikes me as strange as much as the time being midnight in both timezones...

Comment: But at least that's the same in both cases.